# Convert React , Electron and RestApi to exe

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, electron, rest

I develop an application desktop using electron with react and Rest Api(node, express, mongoose) and i can convert only react and electron to setup . exe without RestApi. I'm wondering if I can do it all of them (React , Electron and RestApi) to the same file exe.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You already have frontend figured out (reactjs's built html).
Now, For the REST API you need to run a server i.e backend.

For that to work you can refer to duplicate questions.

- [Run Node.js server file automatically after launching Electron App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458417/run-node-js-server-file-automatically-after-launching-electron-app)
- [NodeJS Electron with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161836/nodejs-electron-with-express)

The 2nd link worked before for me.